# Failing to Pass String Parameters in a jQuery ajax call to an ASP.NET webmethod

Tags: jquery, webmethod

I am having some issues with Passing Parameters in a jQuery ajax call to an ASP.NET webmethod and it is **BUGGING** me all day long.

I've seen the solution of how it is being done and yet it is not working for me.

Here is some code:

```
function GetString() {

    var name = "yan";
    var fam = "key";
    alert(name + " " + fam);

    $.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "'Services/MyService.asmx/returnString",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: "{ 'fname' : '" + name + "' , 'lname' : '" + fam + "'}",
    //data: "{ 'fname' : 'name' , 'lname' : 'fam'}",
    //data: '{"fname":"Chris","lname":"Brandsma"}',
    data: "{'fname':'Chris','lname':'Brandsma'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)   //what to do if fails
    {
        alert('bad, ' + errorThrown + ", " + jqXHR.responseText + ", " + textStatus);
    },
    success: function (data)           //what to do if succedded
    {
        alert(data.d);
    }
});
```

}

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string returnString(string fname, string lname)
{
    return ("my name is " + fname + " " + lname);
}
```

and that's the error I get:
[image: Error: responseText:]

You can see that I've tried several ways of accomplishing it, none worked.
Can anybody point the mistake/ suggest another solution???

thanks in advance

Comment: Is webmethod on an aspx page or webservice, because aspx's webmethod does not support GET.

Comment: try `data: {firstName:"Chris",lastName:"Brandsma"}`instead of `data: "{'firstName':'Chris','lastName':'Brandsma'}"`

Comment: I have created a webservice and the C# code is written in that file. so I guess its not an aspx but a webservice...

Comment: @mamdouh - it still doesn't work and fires the error: `alert("bad")` :(

Comment: Seriously, Hadn't Anybody encountered such issue ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I've been trying in the last 24 hours, I've finally succeded :) 
Here's how it goes:

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false)]
public string returnString2(string fname, string lname)
{
    return "{ \"FirstName\" : "\" + fname + "\" , \"LastName\" : "\" + lname + "\"}";
}
```

**Notice that the `(UseHttpGet=false)`**

Jquery:

```
function GetString2() {

    var name = "yan";
    var fam = "key";
    alert(name + " " + fam);

    $.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Services/MyService.asmx/returnString2',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ fname: "yan" , lname: "key" }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)   //what to do if fails
    {
        alert('bad, ' + errorThrown + ", " + jqXHR.responseText + ", " + textStatus);
    },
    success: function (data)           //what to do if succedded
    {
        alert(data.d);
        var person = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        alert(person.FirstName);
    }
});
```

}

**Notice how `type:"Post"` and that `data` line are changed**

Thanks everyone who tried to help, all of you contributed a little bit :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code change

```
    type: "GET",
```

to

```
    type: "POST",
```

Comment: I already gave it a try.. In addition, in my code behind I have `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` doesn't that mean that I should've used `type: "GET"` in the first place?!?! 
Anyway, I've tried another suggestion, which didn't comply as well: `data: JSON.stringify({ fname: "yan" , lname: "key" }),`

Comment: When you have no parameters, "GET" works. When you have a parameter, "POST" work but "GET" does not. Please, explain why.